# configure error: X is not found

Tags: configure, x11

I get the following running a ./configure script:

```
configure: error: You must have a working copy of X installed.
```

I wonder as I do run an X server. What should I install here?

Answer (score 1):

I had to install

```
xorg-x11-server-devel
```

package on CentOS to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install
`libx11-dev`
package on xubuntu 16.04 to make it work.